# Flag module - no ajax on link update

Tags: 7, ajax

I am trying to update multiple [flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) links on a page. When I update the links the ajax functionality is gone.

This is the code I am trying to use. Any ideas?

```
$(document).bind('flagGlobalBeforeLinkUpdate', function(event, data) {
var $wrappers = $('.flag-wrapper.flag-' + data.flagName + '-' + data.contentId).not(data.link);
var $newLink = $(data.newLink);
$('.flag-message', $newLink).hide();
$wrappers = $newLink.replaceAll($wrappers);
Drupal.attachBehaviors($wrappers);
});
```

*edit- I have 2 flag links on a page(the same link). When I click one I want the other link to update. The problem is that the other link doesn't attach to the ajax event.

Comment: I think you might need to give more of the problem you're trying to solve. What other code are you running, i.e. how are you executing your js? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Malks It looks like i left some code out. `$(document).bind('flagGlobalBeforeLinkUpdate', function(event, data) { ... code above ... });` I have 2 flag links on my page (the same link) and when I click one I want the other one to update as well. It updates the link but the ajax functionality is gone. Thanks.